# Speech to Text: interim_results=true, Won't detect keywords on-the-fly when "final": false?

Tags: ibm-watson

I use speech to text API and set interim_result=true. I need to detect keywords when the sentence is not finished yet (i.e. "final": false). However, it seems when "final" is false, it will not detect keywords. Is it expected?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, that is correct. Keywords wont be detected in the interim results, only on results marked as final.